# asp.net Need some design advice about complex form and validators

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

We have a asp.net web form developed in C#. This form has around 100 fields and it's very dynamic form. It's  dynamic in the sense, when you first start you see only about 20 fields,but as you go on making differnt selctions in the forms, panels containging fields are displayed or hidden. Almost each field is validated on the client side using .net validators. Javascript is used to turn on/off validators depending on if the panel they are in is visiable or not.

This form has some bugs and it's pain in the rear to debug this form because almos every field has at least 2 validators - require and/regular experssion. Also some of the fields when selected do autopostback. most often users cannot submit the form because one/more validators are still enable but the fields that they are attached to are invisible so it's hard to debug as which validtor is causing the problem.

So here my design question.

- What is the easier way to debug validators in this case? How to find which validtors are still on?
- Instead of using asp.net validators, Should I just recode the form and
  use JavaScript for validation, at least that way it will be esier
  to debug validtors.
- Any design consideration? Since this form is such a pain, we won't
  mind redesigning it, and doing it the right way.

I was thinking what if I create a single JavaScript function that is called every time a form field is either clicked or changed, this JavaScript function will be called and it will check all 100 form fields. If the form field is visible, the corresponding validator is enabled, otherwise disabled.

What do you think of the approach?

Thanks for your time and advice in advance.

Comment: A Form with 100 fields sounds problematic to me. Maybe try and move some fields to another Form. Have you considered using the wizard control?

Comment: When re-reading your question I wonder why do people complicate their lives so much, while keeping things neat and clean is much easier and pays off better.

Answer (score 0):

Just from a Usability point of view, I'd strongly recommend to keep forms as short as possible and to have a list of forms to fill on an overview page. Users need to pause now and then, and to save work mid-way.

There are reasons to not subdivide a form (surveys from anonymous users, for example). But if users are authenticated and forced to fill out the forms (by laws or other real-world constraints) then you should really have 5 forms of 20 fields or so.

Once the complexity is lower, you'll have an easier time approaching those other problems.

For your questions:

I'd advise to use ASP.NET validators. They are declined into two worlds: client-side for Usability (reactivity) and server-side for security. You'll have a hard time to have the same ease of use and consistency without ASP.NET validators.

The regular expression SHOULD NOT be debugged in the validator but in a separate moment (unit testing or a simple script with tons of test strings) and then dropped-in with little testing afterwards.

On autopostback: why? Try to avoid it or use AJAX.

You'll have a lot of work to do, to follow these advises, but be confident that they'll be worth it. Especially for new projects.